Who can perform preventive maintenance? Only owner or owner/operator?
I've a question regarding who can perform preventive maintenance. I had some instructors telling me that only the registered owner can perform it  according to FAR part43 appendix A (c)(30)(i). But FAR part43.3(g) states a pilot with at least private license owning or operating an aircraft can perform preventive maintenance. Which is correct?

Appendix A (c)(30)(i) specifically refers to primary category aircraft:

The inspection and maintenance tasks prescribed and specifically identified as preventive maintenance in a primary category aircraft type certificate or supplemental type certificate holder's approved special inspection and preventive maintenance program when accomplished on a primary category aircraft provided:

It states that the owner (and only the owner) can perform certain tasks in addition to the tasks listed in the rest of Appendix A (c). The operator can still do any other preventive maintenance that is not part of a special inspection and preventive maintenance program mentioned in this subpart.
Primary category aircraft are fairly unusual. They're basically a precursor to modern light sport aircraft. They are type certificated, but under a relaxed process compared to normal category aircraft. You can read about them in AC 21-37.

Is that so the owner positively knows the maintenance was done (because they did it themself) and to a known quality of proficiency/correctly with the qualified parts and procedures - no future post accident name pointing.

@civitas The additional maintenance that can be done on primary category aircraft requires you to go through a training program. It's somewhat of a moot point- primary category aircraft that have been maintained by the owner are not allowed to be rented so the operator is typically the owner anyway.
